# What Triggers the Generation of a Factory in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, compiler, dependency-injection, factory

Magento 2 contains a number of class files that are either pre-generated, or are generated on the fly.  They live in

```
var/generated
```

These generated files include factory classes.  From [the documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html#dep-inj-mod-type-fact), it's my understanding that a programmer uses factory classes to instantiate "non-injectable" objects.  A "non-injectable" object is an object that **can't** be added via `__constructor` dependency injection, usually because it requires user input to instantiate.

What's not clear from the documentation is how Magento 2 knows it needs to generate a factory class.  This bit

> If a non-existent factory is encountered by object manager in runtime mode or compiler, the object manager generates the factory.

makes it sound like if I use a factory class in the object manager (or, by extension, in the dependency injection __constructors), that Magento 2 will generate it for me.  But **how does the object manager know the thing I'm requesting is a factory?**

Also, there seems to be [two](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler-single.html) [commands](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler-multi.html) for automatically generating (or "compiling") all the generated classes.  Running either of these commands generates a large number of Factory classes.  **What configuration and/or code files are these commands looking at to generate the needed factory objects?**

I know that tracing the object manager and/or command code all the way down would reveal this, but I'm hoping to avoid that long and arduous journey.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some interesting code location for how this all works together:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Code/GeneratorTest.php#L40

With the different types coming mostly from here
https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Code/Generator but also from here https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Code/Generator for the Interception code.

It is all triggered by the autoloader here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php#L32

```
public function load($className)
{
    if (!class_exists($className)) {
        return Generator::GENERATION_ERROR != $this->_generator->generateClass($className);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I am digging in this same pea soup right now. My understanding so far is that all of the stuff that gets auto generated at `/var/generation` is done from the preferences and interfaces declared in `app/etc/di.xml`.

Interfaces and preferences of yours are going to be declared in the `di.xml` file in your `/app/code/Vendor/<module>/etc/di.xml`.

It knows to generate the object(s) for you because you have declared an interface in your `__constructor` AND have declared a preference for that interface either globally or locally in the appropriate `di.xml` file.

I offer three grains of salt with my comments.

Comment: +1 for the useful information -- but it seems like Factories come from somewhere other than the `di.xml` files -- you can send something into the object manager that ends in Factory and it will generate a file for you.

Comment: Does this help? http://bit.ly/1BOtdie

Answer (score 9):

I haven't found in the code, the conditions for which the factories are generated, but from my understanding a factory class is generated when it is requested and not found.
There are some reserved keywords `Factory, Proxy, Interceptor`, if used, will trigger code generation when the specific classes are not found.
I will post back as soon as I find the code that triggers the factory generation.
So, if you request the class `Some\Namespace\HereFactory` and the class does not exist, because it ends with the keyword `Factory` it will be generated in the `var/generation/Some/Namespace/HereFactory.php`

Comment: Looks like docs should be updated since ObjectManager isn't really the one generating. Special auto loader is part of the answer.  https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php

Comment: That lines up with my experience (see gist.github.com/astorm/f245ce9c761c9a8053aa), but it does raise the question 1. Where does this happen in the object manager code (i.e. what's the actual convention) 2. How does the compiler/generator know what factories to generate?