# Magento2: How to add pre defined data (installData.php) for Custom Module

Tags: magento2, setup, factory, installdata

I am working on creation of custom module and it is going to be stuck in a problem where i want to add some predefined data to my custom module while installation, so for that i review pre defined modules and found that there is a file `installData.php` inside `Setup` of a custom module

I reviewed `module-cms` all thing is well set and find out a class included inside `vendor\magento\module-cms\Setup\insatallData.php`

```
namespace Magento\Cms\Setup;

use Magento\Cms\Model\Page;
use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
```

**use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;**

where to find this `PageFactory` class, because if i am able to find this then in that manner i am able create a `Factory` class for my own module.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PageFactory is auto generate class in magento2.

Module with model class have factory class. You can check this PageFactroy class inside

`var/generation/Magento/Cms/Model/PageFactory.php`.
All factory class are autogenerated and its path are found under `var/generation/Magento/{{Modulename}}/Model/{{ModelclassFactory.php}}`

If your module is custom module not magento core module at that time you have to check Factory class inside `var/generation/{{Packagename}}/{{Modulename}}/Model/{{ModelclassFactory.php}}.`

ex. your custom module is Company/Test and Test module contain model class,
You have to check TestFactory class inside `var/generation/Company/Test/Model/TestFactory.php`

Comment: model class created, but its not generating any `model factory` class, any reason?

Comment: i have updated my answer plz check again.

Answer (score 1):

PageFactory in Magento 2

go through this thread [What Triggers the Generation of a Factory in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69587/what-triggers-the-generation-of-a-factory-in-magento-2) you will understand.