# "Invalid Factory for nonexistent class" (setup:di:compile error)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, di, code-generation, factory

I get the following error when running `bin/magento setup:di:compile`:

```
Errors during configuration scanning:
        IntegerNet\SolrSuggest\Implementor\Factory\AppFactory
                Invalid Factory for nonexistent class IntegerNet\SolrSuggest\Implementor\Factory\App in file [...]/vendor/integer-net/solr-magento2/src/Model/Cache.php
```

The `AppFactory` is actually a real interface from a library, it should not be generated by Magento. As far as I understood the generation, factories are only generated if the class does not exist. I double checked that the file exists and the directory is registered in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`.

This is how the class that depends on the factory looks like:

#### Cache.php

```
<?php
namespace IntegerNet\Solr\Model;
use IntegerNet\SolrSuggest\Implementor\Factory\AppFactory;
class Cache
{
    /**
     * @var AppFactory
     */
    private $appFactory;
    public function __construct(AppFactory $appFactory)
    {
        $this->appFactory = $appFactory;
    }
}
```

And this is the factory:

#### AppFactory.php

```
<?php
namespace IntegerNet\SolrSuggest\Implementor\Factory;
use IntegerNet\SolrSuggest\Implementor\Factory\CacheWriterFactory;
use IntegerNet\SolrSuggest\Implementor\Factory\ConfigFactory;
interface AppFactory extends ConfigFactory, CacheWriterFactory
{
}
```

I defined a preference for the interface in `di.xml`:

```
<preference for="IntegerNet\SolrSuggest\Implementor\Factory\AppFactory" type="IntegerNet\Solr\Model\Bridge\AppFactory" />
```

Any idea what I can do about these messages?

### Observation

In developer mode where I don't explicitly run the compile command, I don't get any errors. And although I get these error messages, compilation runs through and everything works - which proves that the factory classes can be used.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69587/what-triggers-the-generation-of-a-factory-in-magento-2 may this help

Comment: @AnkitShah unfortunately not, all agree that generation only takes place if the class does not exist, which I also thought, but does not seem to be the case for me.

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting issue and I'm not entirely sure why is this happening.

What I can suggest is debugging directly in the `_findMissingClasses` method from `Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner` that's where the error is coming from:

```
protected function _findMissingClasses($file, $classReflection, $methodName, $entityType)
{
    $missingClasses = [];
    if ($classReflection->hasMethod($methodName)) {
        $constructor = $classReflection->getMethod($methodName);
        $parameters = $constructor->getParameters();
        /** @var $parameter \ReflectionParameter */
        foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
            preg_match('/\[\s\<\w+?>\s([\w\\\\]+)/s', $parameter->__toString(), $matches);
            if (isset($matches[1]) && substr($matches[1], -strlen($entityType)) == $entityType) {
                $missingClassName = $matches[1];
                try {
                    if (class_exists($missingClassName)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                }
                $sourceClassName = $this->getSourceClassName($missingClassName, $entityType);
                if (!class_exists($sourceClassName) && !interface_exists($sourceClassName)) {
                    $this->_log->add(
                        Log::CONFIGURATION_ERROR,
                        $missingClassName,
                        "Invalid {$entityType} for nonexistent class {$sourceClassName} in file {$file}"
                    );
                    continue;
                }
                $missingClasses[] = $missingClassName;
            }
        }
    }
    return $missingClasses;
}
```

That method is called from the `_fetchFactories` method which also logs the same error so you need to find out, where the error is coming from exactly and from there you should be able to start debugging:

```
protected function _fetchFactories($reflectionClass, $file)
{
    $factorySuffix = '\\'.ucfirst(FactoryGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE);
    $absentFactories = $this->_findMissingClasses(
        $file,
        $reflectionClass,
        '__construct',
        ucfirst(FactoryGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE)
    );
    foreach ($absentFactories as $key => $absentFactory) {
        if (substr($absentFactory, -strlen($factorySuffix)) == $factorySuffix) {
            $entityName = rtrim(substr($absentFactory, 0, -strlen($factorySuffix)), '\\');
            $this->_log->add(
                Log::CONFIGURATION_ERROR,
                $absentFactory,
                'Invalid Factory declaration for class ' . $entityName . ' in file ' . $file
            );
            unset($absentFactories[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $absentFactories;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking @Raphael's suggestion, I looked through `Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner`::`_findMissingClasses` with the debugger on, the issue arises from this block of code

```
if (class_exists($missingClassName)) {
    continue;
}
```

In your case @fschmengler `$missingClassName` is `IntegerNet\SolrSuggest\Implementor\Factory\AppFactory` which as you said is an *`interface`* not a `class`.

Revising the core code to

```
if (interface_exists($missingClassName) || class_exists($missingClassName)) {
    continue;
}
```

seems to eliminate the problem. Maybe this is a bug worth mentioning to the Magento developers?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar errors

```
Interception cache generation... 6/9 [==================>---------]  66% 58 secs 442.0 MiBErrors during configuration scanning:
        Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyInterfaceFactory
                Invalid Factory for nonexistent class Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyInterface in file /home/companyde/staging-m2.company.de/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Fixtures/CompaniesFixture.php
        Magento\NegotiableQuote\Model\NegotiableQuoteFactory
                Invalid Factory for nonexistent class Magento\NegotiableQuote\Model\NegotiableQuote in file /home/companyde/staging-m2.company.de/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Fixtures/NegotiableQuotesFixture.php
        Magento\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Company\CollectionFactory
                Invalid Factory for nonexistent class Magento\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Company\Collection in file /home/companyde/staging-m2.company.de/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Fixtures/NegotiableQuotesFixture.php
        Magento\NegotiableQuote\Api\Data\HistoryInterfaceFactory
                Invalid Factory for nonexistent class Magento\NegotiableQuote\Api\Data\HistoryInterface in file /home/companyde/staging-m2.company.de/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Fixtures/NegotiableQuotesFixture.php
        Magento\SharedCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\SharedCatalog\CollectionFactory
                Invalid Factory for nonexistent class Magento\SharedCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\SharedCatalog\Collection in file /home/companyde/staging-m2.company.de/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Fixtures/SharedCatalogsFixture.php
Total Errors Count: 5
```

I solved these errors by deleting the following files:

```
/home/companyde/staging-m2.company.de/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Fixtures/NegotiableQuotesFixture.php
/home/companyde/staging-m2.company.de/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Fixtures/SharedCatalogsFixture.php
/home/companyde/staging-m2.company.de/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Fixtures/CompaniesFixture.php
```

I think these files are from magento enterprise B2B module. I removed the module with `composer remove` but the files where not deleted as well and caused the error.

Comment: ➕ similar experience. Running `composer install`, `bin/magento c:c`, and `bin/magento set:up` resolved this issue for me.